# How can I set a delayOut timer for the jQuery tooltip plugin?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm using the [jQuery tooltip plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip) (Bassistance). Now I want to set a delayOut timer on the tooltip, but this is no option of the plugin.
I also want that the tooltip remains visible when I hover the tooltip.

Do you know how I can achieve these two features without using another jQuery plugin?

Comment: [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) ftw, even though you don't want to use a different plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*set a delayOut*

To make a delay out timer you have to create a new timer parameter in your jquery.tooltip.js, like this:

```
var helper = {},
        // the current tooltipped element
        current,
        // the title of the current element, used for restoring
        title,
        // timeout id for delayed tooltips
        tID,
            // timeout id for tooltip timeout
        tDelayoutID,
        // IE 5.5 or 6
        IE = $.browser.msie && /MSIE\s(5\.5|6\.)/.test(navigator.userAgent),
        // flag for mouse tracking
        track = false;
```

Next, add a delayOut parameter for the tooltip:

```
$.tooltip = {
        blocked: false,
        defaults: {
            delay: 200,
            delayOut: 5000,
            fade: false,
            showURL: true,
            extraClass: "",
            top: 15,
            left: 15,
            id: "tooltip"
        },
        block: function() {
            $.tooltip.blocked = !$.tooltip.blocked;
        }
    };
```

Next, create the timer:

```
    function show() {
      tID = null;

      if (tDelayoutID)
        clearTimeout(tDelayoutID);

      if( settings(this).delayOut )
        tDelayoutID = setTimeout(hide, settings(this).delayOut);

      if ((!IE || //...
```

*tooltip remains visible when I hover the tooltip*

To do this you have to check the mouse position in the hide method, and if it's still on the tooltip just return. You may have to remove the .mouseout(hide) and .click(hide) events, depending on what you're looking for in combination with the timer.